# How to execute ogr2ogr.exe through a java process in Windows 10?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, java

I've tried to run the program ogr2ogr.exe through a java process, the process command executes fine in a cmd-window but not from my java program. The error code I get is:

ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
connection to server at "27.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I have opened up to trust for all users and connections in pg_hba.conf.
I've tried with ' ' around 'user' 'dbname' and 'password' in the connection argument.

If I use:`gdalEnv.put("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH",  "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\plugins;C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\plugins-external");`
I'll get this error code:
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-3.5.2\bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

But it is the place where ogr_OCI.dll is stored!

The command I'm running is:
C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-3.5.2\bin\gdal\apps\ogr2ogr.exe -f ESRI Shapefile c:\Temp\FARMAR.shp "PG:host=27.0.0.1 user=user password=pwd dbname=aaaa" Farmar -skipfailures

The simple test program:

```
package org.geotools.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.gdal.gdal.gdal;
import org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI;

public class testjni {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gdal.AllRegister();
        gdalJNI.HasThreadSupport();
        gdalJNI.isAvailable();
        
        ProcessBuilder gdalProcess = new ProcessBuilder();
        Map<String, String> gdalEnv = gdalProcess.environment();
        gdalEnv.put("USERNAME", "user");

        gdalEnv.put("GDAL_DATA",  "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2" + "\\bin\\gdal-data");
        //gdalEnv.put("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH",  "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\plugins;C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\plugins-external");
        gdalEnv.put("PROJ_LIB",  "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\proj7\\share");
        gdalEnv.put("GDAL_CACHEMAX" , "40%");
        gdalEnv.put("SKD_ROOT",  "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2" + "\\");
        /*
        gdalEnv.put("PGDATA", "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\15\\data");
        gdalEnv.put("PGDATABASE", "postgres");
        gdalEnv.put("PGUSER", "postgres");
        gdalEnv.put("PGPORT", "5432");
        gdalEnv.put("PGLOCALEDIR", "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\15\\share\\locale");
        */
        gdalProcess.redirectErrorStream(true);
        gdalProcess.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\apps"));
        
        
        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-3.5.2\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\ogr2ogr.exe");
        cmd.add("-f");
        cmd.add("ESRI Shapefile");
        cmd.add("c:\\Temp\\FARMAR.shp");
        cmd.add("\"PG:host=27.0.0.1 user=user password=pwd dbname=aaaa\"");
        //cmd.add("\"PG:host=27.0.0.1 user='user' password='pwd' dbname='aaaa'\"");
        cmd.add("Farmar");
        cmd.add("-skipfailures");
        ProcessBuilder b = gdalProcess;
        b.command(cmd);
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = b.start();
            InputStream processOutput = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processOutput));
            String str1 = null;
            while ((str1 = bufIn.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str1);
            }
            bufIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error about ogr_OCI.dll is not related. It is needed by the Oracle spatial (OCI) driver and you are using PostGIS. The meaningful error is the one saying that connection to your local PostGIS fails. The connection string looks good to me, hard to say what is wrong in your system.

Comment: I would expect `PG:host=27.0.0.1` to be `PG:host=127.0.0.1`